# Difficulties with SortedList

Tags: c#, xna

I always get this error message in the following line:

```
posDiffRectFList.Add(posDiff_Float, Backgrounds.levellistshapes[j]);
```

ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.

What is wrong? What should I change?

For example:
Is it possible to add this to a `SortedList`? Or is that not possible because it is two times the same key(1.5f)?

```
posDiffRectFList.Add(1.5f, (10,20,100,100));

posDiffRectFList.Add(1.5f, (50,70,60,60));


SortedList<float, System.Drawing.RectangleF> posDiffRectFList = new SortedList<float, System.Drawing.RectangleF>();
for (int j = 0; j <= Backgrounds.LevelListTiles.Count - 1; j++)
{
  posDiff = new Vector2((int)((Backgrounds.LevelListTiles[j].X + Backgrounds.LevelListTiles[j].Width * 0.5) - (Basketball_Rect.X + Basketball_Rect.Width * 0.5)), (int)((Backgrounds.LevelListTiles[j].Y + Backgrounds.LevelListTiles[j].Height * 0.5) - (Basketball_Rect.Y + Basketball_Rect.Height * 0.5)));
  posDiff_Float = posDiff.Length();
  posDiffRectFList.Add(posDiff_Float, Backgrounds.LevelListTiles[j]);
}
//check for collision between tiles and basketball, beginning with the lowest posDiff_Float and his corresponding RectangleF
for (int j = 0; j <= posDiffRectFList.Count - 1; j++)
{ 
 if (kugelNewRect.IntersectsWith(posDiffRectFList.Values[j]))
```

Comment: Isn't that obvious from the exception message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.collections.sortedlist.add.aspx) documentation states that you cannot add the same key twice.

> ArgumentException - An element with the specified key already exists in the SortedList object.